# Bash script, reading from set of files in a directory

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a set of files places in a directory, and I want to read the second line from each file, extract the first substring which is placed between braces " () " and rename that file with this substing.

I'm not looking for a full bash code, I just need some hints and commands to use for each step

Example:
a file has these lines:

```
/* USER: 202166 (just_yousef) */
/* PROBLEM: 2954 (11854 - Egypt) */
/* SUBMISSION: 11071978 */
/* SUBMISSION TIME: 2012-12-25 15:49:25 */
/* LANGUAGE: 3 */
```

I need to take substring "11854 - Egypt" and rename the file with it, and proceed to the next file.

Comment: You'll probably want to have a look at cut.
http://ss64.com/bash/cut.html

Split -l might also be useful in combination with gawk/awk:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/618438/split-large-file-in-bash
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/

How I'd approach this is split lines, then grab the () substring, and then use "mv" to rename the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from each file

```
for f in /the/directory/*; do
  # ...
done
```

> read the second line [and] extract the first substring which is placed between [parentheses]

```
v=$(sed -n '2 { s/[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*/\1/; p; q }' < "${f}")
```

> rename that file

Use the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use  For each in the  directory    pipe the same with xargs and filter   the files you want to read . and pass the file name with path to the Script which will do reading of second line.

For the script  open the  file  and extract the String a per the logic.

THen close the file  and use rename command  to the file name you have as an input to this script.

rename $0  .txt

If the file structure is recurrrsive the extract the  name before the last /  using index of  method of string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `sed` may well be the tool for the job:

```
for i in *
do
    j=`sed -e '1d;2{;s/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/;q;}' "$i"`
    test -z "$j" || test -e "$j" || mv -v "$i$ "$j"
done
```

I put the test for `$j` empty or already existing as safeguards; you might think of others.  I also gave the `-v` flag to `mv` so you can see what it is doing.

You may prefer to use `sed -n` and just act on lines matching `PROBLEM:` if that's more reliable than always using the second line.